# GeoPortal Managing Tool

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis

i know in this site everybody more or less have been setup a geoportal for showing their basemaps and analysis on local or net for their workers or conserned people in the net.

it is obvious that in the gis platform there are lots of datas and machines for serving all requests from people. if you are alone in your work or more knowledgeable from other workers in the same place it is meant to there are lots of works to do in your professional business if you respect your work.

owing to you loving your work, doing more work something like coding, designing or mapping, working a lot probably not bother you. but when you are sleeping at middle of the night or with your favorite friends come together with stealthy way for doing something, so at your special moment when comes a call about job makes you bother or it disgusts you from your work.

at now for managing and controling the gis something like only restarting services as apache, nginx or iis; your database maybe swelled; maybe image server not working.

What tools are you advise me for controlling not everything but more in gis or for gis?

Do you have any open source tool for this?

A program with defining database controlling size of data, service status or restarting them.

Comment: what is your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For monitoring and simple corrective action, take a look at [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), it can go a long way towards keeping services up and running.